# Varien's product.js method override is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, prototype-js

I want to override `initPrices` method.

For this in js folder i have created directory scommerce and in that directory created file `product.js`

In product.js file code to override is as following:

```
Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.initPrices = Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.initPrices.wrap(function(){ this.containers[5] = 'product-price-' + this.productId + '_clone'; });
```

In `local.xml` file i have add

```
<catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
               <script>varien/product.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>scommerce/product.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

But it is not working.

I am following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962443/how-should-magento-varien-js-files-be-changed link.

Comment: Have `<action .....</action>` in single line, sometime that helps.

Comment: It is not working